# How to collect a number from the body of an email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have been able find the email in my Outlook inbox however I am trying to collect a number after a specific phrase in the email.

Halfway through the email it says "Invoice: " and then gives a number that can vary in size. I want to collect this number and nothing after it. The word "Invoice: " never changes so we can use that as a base but the following numbers can vary in size.

Also I need this as Long rather than a String.

It seems we may want to use the split function.

Comment: Always helps to show the code you already have.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tim Williams suggested, showing what you've already tried makes it easier for us to help.

You could extract the number with a regular expression (regex). This sample code extracts a long from a fixed string. You should be able to adapt it to your needs by setting `strText` to the email body instead of the hardcoded string here. To use a regex, set a reference to `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5` (it's 5.5 in my Excel 2019).

```
Sub InvoiceNum()
    Dim regexTarget As RegExp, strSearch As String, strText As String, bMatch As Boolean, vntOutput As Variant
    
    Set regexTarget = New RegExp
    strText = " blah blah blah Invoice: 12345 followed by more blah blah"
    
    strSearch = "Invoice: [0-9]+" ' Matches "Invoice: " followed by 1 or more numerals
    
    With regexTarget
        .Pattern = strSearch
        bMatch = .Test(strText)
        If bMatch = True Then
            vntOutput = .Execute(strText).Item(0).Value
            vntOutput = Trim(Replace(vntOutput, "Invoice: ", "")) ' Remove "Invoice: " and any extraneous spaces
            vntOutput = CLng(vntOutput)  ' Convert string to Long
        End If
    End With
        
End Sub
```